# Charts within tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, chart.js

I am struggling w/ a section in my code where I want to display charts within tabs. Each tab should contain a specific chart.
For the tabs, I am using the directive `md-tab`of `AngularMaterial 1.1.0` for `Angular JS`. For the charts, I am using `Chart.js`.
Basically, `Chart.js` uses canvas to display charts. See this example of chart display :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

It appears to me than chart.js uses the canva ID to display the chart within it.

Knowing that, here is my code :

HTML :

```
<md-tabs id="results" class="md-primary"  md-center-tabs md-swipe-contents md-dynamic-height>
  <md-tab id="tab{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="thisResultComponent in statistics track by $index" md-on-select="drawChart(thisResultComponent, $index)">
    <md-tab-label> {{thisResultComponent.tablabel}} </md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body class="result-content">
      <canvas class="result-chart" id="chart{{$index}}"> </canvas>
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Controller (js) :

```
$scope.drawBarChart = function(thisComponent, thisIndex) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("chart"+thisIndex);
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: thisComponent.chartData,
    options: thisComponent.chartOptions
  });
};
```

However... It does not work.
I have an error at the line "var myChart = new Chart[etc.]", as if the canvas with the correct ID can not be found.

However, when I inspect my code, the canvas do have the right ID.
So I think it might be an issue of rendering ; the `md-on-select = "drawChart(thisComponent, $index)"` seem to be launch before the id of the canvas is rendered. That would explain the drawChart function fail to find a canvas with the correct ID at the time it runs...

I tried different solutions but I am struggling !

- using ng-include w/ the index as a variable in the child scope : could not make it work
- using on-load directive : could not make it work

(I found similar questions, but they only involve a limited number of tabs. In my case, I don't know how many tabs I will have in my data).